# Suma de fecha dependiendo de una frecuencia de días en jQuery

Tags: jquery

Hola amigos tengo un sistema de matrículas y quiero hallar la fecha de finalización automática, la suma de fecha varía entre

```
L-M-V (Lunes, miercoles y viernes),
M-J (Martes, jueves),
S (Sábados)
```

[image: Matricula en sistema]

si yo deseo que mi inicio sea Lunes 13/11/2017 si le sumo 5 dias mi fecha fin debe de ser Miércoles 22/11/2017

La suma lo hago en jquery, pero solo me sale 18/11/2017 porque suma 5 dias.

Comment: 13/11/2017 si le sumo 5 dias mi fecha fin debe de ser Miércoles 22/11/2017   13+5 = 18 eso esta bien jaja no se te entiende sorry

Comment: claro si sumo me 5 dias me sale 18....lo que yo quiero es que me sume solo los Lunes - miércoles y viernes....osea saldría 22/11/2017

Comment: pero puedes poner tu codigo que llevas? si no como podemos ver

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tienes que obtener (de alguna parte) un arreglo con los días que quieres meter en tu "lista blanca", fijar cuántas clases quieres ofrecer, y luego a contar de hoy ir añadiendo un día a la fecha hasta que se hayan realizado todas las clases. Metes eso en un bucle que termina cuando ya diste las N clases que comprometiste en la matrícula.

Por ejemplo, las clases se dan los días Lúnes (1), Miércoles (3) y Viernes (5). Quieres dar cinco clases a partir de hoy.

```js
var dias=[1,3,5],
    clases=5,
    clase=0,
    fecha=new Date(),
    fecha_texto=fecha.toISOString().split('T')[0];
    
console.log('El índice del día de hoy',fecha_texto,'es',fecha.getDay());    

while(clases>0) {
  if(dias.indexOf(fecha.getDay())!==-1) {
    clases--;
    clase++;
    fecha_texto=fecha.toISOString().split('T')[0];
    console.log('Clase',clase,'será el día ',fecha_texto);
  }
  fecha.setDate(fecha.getDate()+1);

}
console.log('La última clase será el día',fecha_texto);
```

Comment: Muchas gracias....me salió a la perfección

Answer (score 0):

es algo parecido a este codigo lo que vas hacer solo tienes que cambiar el formato de del dia y en el if en lugar de 1 2 3 etc cambias a lun , martes , miercoles etc

```
var f = new Date();
            fechaMayorDeDiciocho= f.getFullYear()-18;
            fechaMenorSesentayCinco= f.getFullYear()-65;
            dia = f.getDate();
            if (dia===1 || dia===2 || dia===3 || dia===4 || dia===5 || dia===6 || dia===7 || dia===8 || dia===9) {
                dia = "0"+dia;
            }
```

aca para guardar el input date javascript

```
   var fechaNacimiento = document.getElementById('fechaNacimiento').value;
    var nacimiento = new Date(fechaNacimiento);
```

Comment: voy a probarlo..:D